# cocos2d - how to draw a bottle sprite with dynamically changing water level

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-iphone, drawing, transparency, sprite

I am trying to draw a (2d) sprite in cocos2d showing a bottle. The bottle shall be able to have a dynamic water level (i.e. the amount of water in the bottle can change over the lifetime of the sprite).

I am wondering how to do this.
I currently have a PNG file of the empty bottle. I adjusted the alpha channel of that PNG so when rendering the sprite I can draw a blue rectangle and render the bottle texture over it. That will give the impression of the water being inside the bottle.

However, the bottle's shape is not a rectangle itself of course, so the water can be seen out of the bounds of the bottle. I can change the bottle image in a way that only the bottle itself is transparent and set the "outside world" to an opaque color & alpha channel value, but that again prevents the "world background" to be visible in that area.

I simply don't have a clue how to realize this in a sane manner. Do I really have to read every pixel of the bottle image, identify which pixel is "inside" of the bottle and then draw the water pixel by pixel? There must be an easier way, right? ;)

Any best practices for these kinds of tasks?

edit: see picture below, to make somewhat clearer, what I am talking about ;)

http://i47.tinypic.com/10rqww0.png

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple images of the bottle with different fill levels and create a sprite sheet from it.

Load the sprite sheet with:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bottle.plist"];
```

To set the water level you change the texture of the bottle with the `setDisplayFrame` method.

Comment: Okay, i am aware of that solution. However, that would require me to draw hundreds and hundreds of images, since it will also be possible to tilt the bottle to left or right. For these cases i cannot use the same images and just rotate them, because the water surface needs to stay horizontal in order to look realistc. Any idea about that? ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you have many possible water levels, you can simply draw CCLayerColor or water texture of the needed size, then draw the sprite with empty bottle over it. then you can just change size of your "water node", no matter if it is CCLayerColor instance or node with some water texture.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how can I make the water to be only drawn "below" the bottle's shape, so that the water does not overlap in the area where the bottle tapers (i.e. Where the bottleneck starts)?

Comment: mmmm... for example, you can have sprite with water for full bottle. then just change size(height) of this sprite